# What Does very interesting mean

Tags: definition

I would just like to know because I do not know the meaning and I would like some clarification so please can someone clarify what it is

Comment: Did you look it up in a dictionary?

Comment: Which part exactly you don't understand?

Comment: You have several questions on this site about what "interesting" means. As several people have commented, you can use a dictionary to answer such a question. For a nice online option, I suggest Merriam-Webster: https://www.merriam-webster.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very interesting has quite a simple definition. It just means that it's something that catches your attention, or it may be pleasing or entertaining. You may say "very interesting" if someone shows you their antique car collection.